# How to capture recaptcha v2 events in angular

Tags: angular, recaptcha, grecaptcha

right now am using reCAPTCHA v2 ("I'm not a robot" Checkbox) in angular(ng-recaptcha). I am able to get the response using the resolved event. but in case of errors I want to capture that and show a custom message instead of pop-up (resolved event is not triggered for the errors). right now, when recaptcha is not able to connect and verify it simply say "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again." as a popup. but I want to capture that event. This is how I have configure right now.

is it possible at all that we can disable the default recaptcha popup since that is directly executing from the scripts?

I have checked this thread from the source, but not seeing that was pull was merged.
https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/122

```
<re-captcha formControlName="reCaptchaV2" (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey="{{reCaptchakey}}"></re-captcha>
```